# prioritizing MySQL v5.6 results

Tags: php, mysql

PHP 7.3 / MySQL v5.6 MyISAM multi-query is using BOOLEAN MODE:

We have a variety of musical instruments in the database. We would like to return a list of all guitars and prioritize the red or white guitars at the top of the result.

Based on the [definition](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html) of the tilde operator, we thought it might be the right approach. Unfortunately with a query of...

```
~guitar red white
```

... the results include all instruments, not just guitars. It looks as if "noise words" (in the definition) means that the word is marked irrelevant in the search query. The result is the same as sending `red white`. Not sure of the value of this.

We've tried some other ideas...

```
~(+guitar) red white  // also throws out "guitar."

+(~guitar) red white  // matches nothing, I guess because we're matching a noise word.

+guitar >(red white) // matches all guitars and doesn't do anything with red or white.

+guitar (>red >white) // same as above.

+guitar +(red white) // matches only guitars that are red or white
```

None of the above give us all guitars, prioritizing the red and white ones. We don't know what customers will type when searching, so red and white are just examples of attributes that should have higher priority. I'll be hard coding a special list to give those attributes the extra emphasis in the code.

Surely there's a simple solution?

By the way, we are using ORDER BY id DESC so the latest IDs come first, but we want the search queries to have precedence. Ideally, the results would show the latest red guitars, latest white guitars, and finally the rest of the guitars from the latest to the earliest.

Comment: `+guitar red white` should give you all guitars, prioritising rows with red or white over those that don't have those words

Comment: Unless a guitar can be white and red at same time (kind of white and red stripes)   looks like you want white or red optionally: `+guitar  >white >red`.

Comment: I just tried both of the above suggestions with my ORDER BY and without it. Unfortunately both return all guitars, but not prioritized as desired.